# how to Access another apps database and insert some record

Tags: java, android, shell, android-sqlite

I have a rooted phone and I want to insert data in another app database from my app.so what i do

my code

```
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH+DB_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

 String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
 Cursor cursor      = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

it throw the exception

```
E/SQLiteLog: v(3850) statement aborts at 1: [PRAGMA journal_mode=TRUNCATE;]
E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: chat_list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access other application database without root access.

If your device is rooted and sqlite is installed and use [RootTools Library](https://github.com/Stericson/RootTools) for run command in android device , you can do it as follows.

For install sqlite use this [apk -> ptSoft.util.sqlite3forroot](http://download.apks.org/?apkid=ptSoft.util.sqlite3forroot&ver=3.5.3.9&server=kautzer4ru)
and  [adb shell method](https://philio.me/installing-sqlite-on-a-rooted-android-phone/)

```
     try {

        String Path = "data/data/com.viber.voip/databases/viber_data";
        String args = "/system/bin/chmod 777 " + Path;

        String args1 = " sqlite3 -csv " + Path;

        String args2 = " SELECT _id,canonized_number from vibernumbers where _id >  12 LIMIT 1;";

        Command command = new Command(0, "su", args, args1, args2, ".exit") {
            @Override
            public void output(int id, String line) {
                 //Check result
            }

            @Override
            public void commandCompleted(int arg0, int arg1) {

            }

            @Override
            public void commandOutput(int arg0, String arg1) {
            }

            @Override
            public void commandTerminated(int arg0, String arg1) {
                String u = arg1;

            }
        };
        RootTools.getShell(true).add(command);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can access another apps database and insert some record by using Content Provider for android